# Python Guessing game

Tags: python

I am a beginner in python using 2.7.11 and i have made a guessing game. Here is my code so far

```
def game():  
    import random
    random_number = random.randint(1,100)
    tries = 0
    low = 0
    high = 100
    while tries < 8:
        if(tries == 0):
          guess = input("Guess a random number between {} and {}.".format(low, high))       
        tries += 1
        try:
          guess_num = int(guess)
        except:
          print("That's not a whole number!")
          break    

        if guess_num < low or guess_num > high:
          print("That number is not between {} and {}.".format(low, high))
          break    

        elif guess_num == random_number:
          print("Congratulations! You are correct!")
          print("It took you {} tries.".format(tries))
          playAagain = raw_input ("Excellent! You guessed the number! Would you like to play again (y or n)? ")
          if playAagain == "y" or "Y":  
            game()

        elif guess_num > random_number:
          print("Sorry that number is too high.")
          high = guess_num
          guess = input("Guess a number between {} and {} .".format(low, high))    

        elif guess_num < random_number:
          print("Sorry that number is too low.")
          low = guess_num
          guess = input("Guess a number between {} and {} .".format(low, high))    

        else:
          print("Sorry, but my number was {}".format(random_number))
          print("You are out of tries. Better luck next time.")
game()
```

1. How would i incorporate a system that makes it so Each time the user guesses the correct number it includes feedback giving the fewest number of guesses it took to correctly guess the number. Like a high score on how many guesses it took them and to change it only if it was beaten

Comment: You might want to change `if playAagain == "y" or "Y":` to `if playAagain.lower() == "y":` or `if playAagain == "y" or playAgain=="Y":`

Comment: Just a few suggestions & questions unrelated to your question. 1). You should use consistent indentation, (the usual convention is 4 spaces per level). 2). Don't import modules inside your functions, do it at the top of the script. 3). Why do you break out of the loop on bad input? 4). Don't restart the game by calling `game()` inside itself, use a loop. 5). By restructuring your code you can get rid of 2 of those `guess = input(...` lines.

Answer (score 0):

you can create  a static variable like this :
`game.highscore = 10`

- and you update it  each time when the user wins the game (check if tries less than highscore)

Answer (score 0):

You could add a `best_score` parameter to your `game` function:

```
def game(best_score=None):
    ...
    elif guess_num == random_number:
        print("Congratulations! You are correct!")
        print("It took you {} tries.".format(tries))

        # update best score
        if best_score is None:
            best_score = tries
        else:
            best_score = min(tries, best_score)

        print("Best score so far: {} tries".format(best_score))

        play_again = raw_input("Excellent! You guessed the number! Would you like to play again (y or n)? ")
        if play_again.lower() == "y":  
            game(best_score)  # launch new game with new best score
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

At the start of your code (before defining the function), add the global variable best_score (or whatever you want to call it), and initialize it as None:

```
best_score = None
```

During the check on whether the number is the correct guess, you can check the number of tries against the best_score, and update accordingly:

```
elif guess_num == random_number:
    global best_score

    # check if best_score needs to be updated
    if best_score == None or tries < best_score:
        best_score = tries
    print("Congratulations! You are correct!")
    print("It took you {} tries.".format(tries))

    # print out a message about the best score
    print("Your best score is {} tries.".format(best_score))
```